# A relevant relentless reluctancy relating related rates?

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I am reviewing some things in calculus, I have these two sample problems with their answers, that I tried to solve another way and got different results. I'd like to understand why what I made yielded different results.

> [image]
> [image]

> [image]
>
> ---
>
> [image]

---

For the first problem, I thought that we have $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}$ and this meant that we need to differentiate implicitly with respect to $x$ and then with respect to $y$:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 2x $$

$$1=2x \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Now we have:

$$2x=\frac{1}{2x} \implies x=\pm \frac{1}{2}$$

Where we get two points:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)\quad \left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

Instead of just one, as given in the answer.

---

In the second one, I tried to answer in the same way, I thought that we needed to find $\frac{dy}{dt}=4 \frac{dx}{dt}$. Differentiating implicitly, we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}= 2x-6$$

$$1= 2x\frac{dx}{dt}-6\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Now we have:

$$2x-6=\frac{4}{2x-6} \implies x \in \{2,4\} $$

And again, we have two points:

$$\left(2,-8\right)\quad \left(4,-8\right)$$

Which is completely off from the point found in the answer. I am a bit confused with the following: Why the way I did fail here? Also, as I have found more solutions than the answer in the first example, I suspect it fails there too.

Comment: Congratulations for your title. I was knowing the ["three Rs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_three_Rs), not the "seven Rs"...

Comment: In the first question, $2x$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}$, not $\frac{dy}{dt}$. Similarly, in the second question, $2x-6$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}$, not $\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Comment: @angryavian Ah. I guess this is the problem I am having. He is asking about y,x as functions of t, instead of x as function of y and y in function of x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both problems, you are given $x$ is a function of $t$ and $y$ is a function of $x$. Writing $x = x(t)$ and $y = y(x(t))$ may help you conceptualise this.

Then, to differentiate $y$ with respect to $t$, we use the chain rule: $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}.$$

For the first problem, we have $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = 2x\frac{dx}{dt}.$$ If $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}$, then $x = \frac{1}{2}$ which implies $y = (\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}$.

You can see that the solution of the second problem given in the book uses the same method.